# How do you query 3 different models in Rails w/ PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to write a query in Rails that involves 3 different models. I need to know which Subscriptions are delivereable. But delivereable is not a column in Subscription but in BasePlan.

```
class BasePlan
  has_many :plans
end

class Plan
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to  :plan
end
```

I've tried joining all three models together to no success:

```
Subscription.joins(:plans).joins(:base_plans).where(queried_column: true)
```

What would be the right way to write the query?

Comment: What are all of the columns you're checking? If you're looking for a base plan then why not jsut start on that model without all the joins?

Comment: I should've added more context. I need to know which Subscriptions are delivereable. But delivereable is not a column in Subscription but in BasePlan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @SteveTurczyn 's answer, you could query like this:
`Subscription.joins(:base_plan).where(base_plans: { queried_column: true })`. You need to first define the through relationship as Steve suggests, then you can traverse the relationship to get the column you need to check on BasePlan.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Subscription` needs to know about it's relationship to `:base_plans` for your code to work.

```
class Subscription
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :base_plan, through: :plan
end
```